# How to access a key object in jQuery with "/"

Tags: jquery

I have the object *localize.data* with this context:

[image]

How can I access to *Navigation*? This is not working:

```
$.localize.data.locales/messages.Navigation
```

Note: I can't remove the slash.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With `[]` like `$.localize.data["locales/messages"].Navigation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
$.localize.data["locales/messages"].Navigation
```